# Dynamically Querying Data - Best Approach

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, data-structures, dynamic-sql

I'm designing an ASP.NET Web Forms application that will be used to query the database dynamically with customized values and filters.

For example:

- Pull up 3 fields: SKU, Description, Price, Color.
- The value of Description should be ProductName + comma + space +
  Description.
- The value of Price should be Price + 10.00.
- The value of Color should be Red if the SKU = 123.

I need to store these "rules" in my SQL database so I can query my database at a later time based on these rules.

Initially, I was thinking to store the rule as SQL text like "ProductName + ', ' + Description", and then use this in my dynamic SQL.

But there's a few things that need wouldn't work if I were to do that:

1. Differentiating between column names and static text. ( I guess the single quotes would take care of that)
2. Different data types (when concatenating let's say)
3. Case statements
4. There are where clauses too.

I need ideas how to go about this - my database structure and how to query from these rules.

I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms, SQL Server database.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a table with Fields (FieldID, FieldName), and Values(Value, ValueType, Datatype, FieldID). So, if I needed **Description** to equal to ProductName + comma + space + Description, I would have a record in Fields table with FieldName="Description" and a value record for ProductName, comma+space and Description. ProductName and Description would have a ValueType of "Field" and ", " (comma space) would have "Static".

I then constructed my sql query with parameters based on these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For this one idea that comes in my mind is to define a business rules table and put values in it like:
**BR_PK      BR_CODE       BR_VALUE**

1               SKU_Fields      P.SKU, P.Description, P.Price, P.Color

2               Price_Val         P.Price + 10

Than you can join dynamic queries to get that data and join with data of other tables but you will have to keep the aliases same as you define in Business rules table.

I will try to find some more better approach but its the one that came in my mind immediately.